# menuItem.InputGestureText not showing shortcut text

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, menuitem

In my application i am creating menu items in code. This is the code for creating menu item

```
public MenuItem getMenuItem(string toolTip, string menuTitle, Uri menuIconUri, int? tagOnlyForHeaders, string shortCutKeyText ="")
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem
        {
            ToolTip = toolTip,
            Header = menuTitle
        };
        if (menuIconUri != null)
        {
            menuItem.Icon = new Image
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(menuIconUri)
            };
        }
        if (tagOnlyForHeaders != null) {
            menuItem.Tag = tagOnlyForHeaders;
        }

        if (shortCutKeyText != "") {
            menuItem.InputGestureText = shortCutKeyText;
        }
        return menuItem;
    }
```

but if I pass value for input Gesture like `ctrl+n` it is not displaying the shortcut text in the menu item while the application is running. what is wrong in this code. can anyone tell a solution for this.

This is how i add menu items

```
//Top level Op menu
        var opMenuItem = utils.getMenuItem("OP", MenuName, null, 0);

        //op registration
        var RegistrationMenuItem = utils.getMenuItem("New Registration", "New Registration",
            new Uri(baseIconUri + "newRegistration.png"), null,"ctrl+n ");
        opMenuItem.Items.Add(opRegistrationMenuItem);
        return opMenuItem;
```

and this is added to the main menu

```
mainMenu.Items.Add(menuItem); // in this case the "opMenuItem"
```

Comment: Is your `MenuItem` a direct child of the `Menu` object?

Comment: Do you mean the `MenuItem` should automatically show the gesture display string when you set some `KeyBinding` for the MenuItem? I think we need to manually set the `InputGestureText` as what you did in your code. The default template also shows that an internal `TextBlock` has its Text bound to `InputGestureText`.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman sorry for being late and yes it is a direct child

Comment: @KingKing i only what it when it is set. AFAIK that is how it works

Comment: the `menuItem` you added is just a top-level menu item so it cannot show InputGestureText. `mainMenu` is a `Menu`, so its direct child is of course a  top-level `MenuItem` (such as in a typical window, you can see top-level `MenuItems` including ***File***, ***View***, ***Help***, ...). In this case you want to show some InputGestureText of such as `File`? That does not make much sense (and even looks ugly), to do that strange requirement, you need some more customizing than just simply setting `InputGestureText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a problem with the library([Material design library](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit)) i was using to style user interface . I've reported the issue and it is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The `InputGestureText` only works when the `MenuItem` is **not** a direct child of the `Menu`(i.e Not directly inside the `Items` collection). If you want to see the `InputGestureText`, you need to add `MenuItem` to the `Items` collection of another `MenuItem`. To illustrate what I said, here is an example in XAML.

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="File" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Z">
        <MenuItem InputGestureText="Ctrl+C" Header="Open"></MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

The `InputGestureText` of the `MenuItem` (Header = "File) is not visible but that of `MenuItem` (Header="Open") is visible.

Comment: By direct child, i meant that it is a menu item in the top level menu when expanded, like file => open ctrl+o

Comment: Can you show how you add the menuItems to the Menu object?

Comment: I see, I have no idea what the problem is then :(